# How to properly calculate 1 second with deltaTime in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to calculate an elapsed second in `deltaTime` but I'm not sure how to do it, because my `deltaTime` constantly prints 0.0166 or 0.0167.

Here is my code:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime
    lastTime = currentTime
```

How do I make it so I can squeeze some logic in here to run every second?

EDIT: I was able to come up with the following, but is there a better way?

```
            deltaTimeTemp += deltaTime
            if (deltaTimeTemp >= 1.0) {
                print(deltaTimeTemp)
                deltaTimeTemp = 0
            }
```

Comment: How is `update` being called? Are you using a CADisplayLink? Or what?

Comment: Every frame within a single scene game using SpriteKite.

Comment: Your scene is running at 60 FPS, so each frame is ~16.6 ms apart. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Every 1 second, I need to spawn an object. I'm hoping I can calculate it using deltaTime in a way that will smoothly handle dips in FPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use SKActions for this type of thing: (written in swift 3)

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
let spawnSomething = SKAction.run {
   //code to spawn whatever you need
}

let repeatSpawnAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, spawnSomething]))

self.run(repeatSpawnAction)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only care about a 1 second interval then you should not be storing the delta for every frame.  Just store the start time and calculate the elapsed time each frame.  When the elapsed time exceeds your 1 second interval then you reset the start time to now.

```
  override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
      let elpasedTimeSinceLastupdate = currentTime - startTime
      //Check if enough time has elapsed otherwise there is nothing to do
      guard elpasedTimeSinceLastupdate > requiredTimeIntervale else {
        return
      }
      startTime = currentTime
      // Do stuff here
  }
```

I ideally you want more than 1 timer, so then you would need to maintain an array of timers and a table of intervals and blocks to call.  This starts to get very complicated and really you should probably just use the built in block Timer in iOS 10, which is much more straight forward:

```
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
        //Do stuff every second here
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid using Timer in SpriteKit. That is far from ideal. You should stick to update method or SKActions. This is because Timer (NSTimer) is not paired with game loop. Means, you will have to implement a custom pause feature. Timer doesn't respect node's, scene's or view's paused state so in many situations you will have to invalidate / re-create and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentTime: number = 0;
    
update(delta) {
    this.time += delta / 1000;
    GameCurrentData.time = Math.floor(this.time);
           
            
    if(this.currentTime !== GameCurrentData.time){
        Globals.emitter?.Call?.("perSecond");
        this.currentTime = GameCurrentData.time;
    }

}
```