# Getting an error in SpriteKit. - Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1007351fc)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game and I am looking for someone to edit my code of why is this crashing with this error code:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1007351fc)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

import SpriteKit

class Winner: SKScene {

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

   backgroundColor = SKColor (red: CGFloat(248), green: CGFloat(248), blue: CGFloat(248), alpha: CGFloat(255)) //UIColor 

    var message = "Great Job! "
    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold")
    label.text = message
    label.fontSize = 22
    label.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.black
    label.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(label)

    run(SKAction.sequence([

        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0),
        SKAction.run() {

            let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
            let scene = GameOver(size: self.size)

            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)


        }
        ]))


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few lines in your question but I think there should be 2 errors in your code.

**The first issue** (who caused **EXC_BREAKPOINT**) could be you write the first lines in :

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        // here there is your code
}
```

and this would explain the presence of the method:
`required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {}` in your scene class,
but the current scene could be initialized with the convenience constructor:

```
public convenience init?(fileNamed filename: String)
```

where you call the SKS relative file scene. In other words, in your `GameViewController` you should have done:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {}
```

instead of:

```
let scene = SKScene(size: self.view.frame.size)
```

so the compiler crash to the :

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

because your class override (then call) the classic init method.

**The second issue** is that a [SKTransition](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktransition) must be called when a `SKScene` object is already presented by an `SKView` object, so you could use your code in :

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("GameScene")
        // here there is your code
}
```

Indeed this method is called immediately after a scene is presented by a view.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you check my updated question where it gets my error from when transition to the scenes.

Comment: It may depend to how you have created your Congratulations class, I don't know it's code..

Comment: I have updated my code once more. You can see my Congratulation Class.

Comment: In your Congratulation class you make a transition to another scene from an init method: take a look to my answer about the second issue..

Comment: So, in my Congratulation class should I add didMove Function and print out the next scene?

Comment: Not only in that class, you cannot execute a SKTransition if your class is not ready..

Comment: I still get the same type of error. I follow your instructions, but It just not working.

Comment: The best thing you can do it in this moment is to apply my answer in a "hello world" spritekit new project template and you can better understand where are your mistakes, after this try to apply these rules to your project, you probably have need to refactor some parts of it

Comment: Hey, Now I am getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error. Can you tell me what is going on?

Comment: Where do you have this issue?

Comment: in my scene where the game is being played

Comment: So you have the first issue of my answer? You have built the scene with SKS file or without?

Comment: I have created a cocoa touch class and set it to spritescene that how the game is it in there.

Comment: **Xcode->File->New->Project->Game** (this is the "hello world" Spritekit template) if you start with it you have a GameScene.SKS and a GameScene.swift, what's your situation?

Comment: Okay, so the crashed is fixed, when I comment the timer countdown and the timer countdown does not work in my first round when they play the game.

Comment: The only timer I can see in your code is a touch counter and it should increase not decrease. Maybe you speak about another timer but I cannot know it.

Comment: You should avoid using Timer in SpriteKit. Timer (NSTimer) is not paired with game cycle. Means, you will have to implement a custom pause feature. Timer doesn't respect node's, scene's or view's paused state so in many situations you will have to invalidate / re-create and stuff. Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41374357/1894067) stack overflow thread